# Error in console with Vue-chartJS and Webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, package, vue-chartjs

I installed `vue-chartjs` and also added `chart.js` both using NPM

When I run `npm start` my server is started but in broswer console i get an error

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_vue_chartjs__.Doughnut.extend is not a function
```

I'm not sure what this mean. I reinstalled all packages also installed this packages separete using `npm install vue-chartjs`

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code of your component? Webpack 3 ?
With vue-chartjs version 3 you have to create your components this way:

```
import {Doughnut} from 'vue-chartjs

export default {
   extends: Doughnut,
   mounted () {
     this.renderChart(data, options)
   }
}
```